# Not using parentheses in constructor call with new (c++)

Tags: c++, parsing, constructor, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

So I had in my main:

```
Class* pC = new Class;
```

It was working as

```
Class* pC = new Class();
```

I realized just  today that I had omitted the parentheses (so I was hit by the "opposite" of the most vexing parse in a way).

My question: Are these two forms equivalent ?

Comment: Both calls invoke the default constructor.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If the class has a default constructor defined, then both are equivalent; the object will be created by calling that constructor.

If the class only has an implicit default constructor, then there is a difference. The first will leave any members of POD type uninitialised; the second will value-initialise them (i.e. set them to zero).

Comment: +1, didn't know about this difference.