# Allocating array in quadriple pointer

Tags: c++

Suppose I have int `****ptr;`. I want to allocate a dynamic 1-dimensional array on the end of this ptr, so when I type `***ptr[4]` I would yield an element. Please, help.

p.s.
I am not using this code in my real applications, it's just an intellectual exercise to understand how pointers work.
I cannot directly do `***ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*size_of_arr));` right? BEcause this way i will not be able to yield any elements

Comment: Is this just an intellectual exercise? If you are actually *using* code like this, you are almost certainly going down the wrong path.

Comment: Parenthesis to the rescue.. Have you tried to parenthesize your code? And perhaps break the process down into 2-3 lines of code, perhaps using some local helper variables?

Comment: No production level code would use such construct. Even asking such from an academical viewpoint, its pretty poorly asked after all.

Comment: Well, if you just can't answer my question  it's not because it's poorly asked, it's because you don't know due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: You had me at _"Suppose I have `int ****ptr;`"_ I mean seriously mate wtf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because intellectual exercises require intellect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int ****ptr;
ptr = new int***();
*ptr = new int**();
**ptr = new int*();
***ptr = new int[size_of_arr];

//access (***ptr)[index]

delete[] ***ptr;
delete **ptr;
delete *ptr;
delete ptr;
```

Comment: thank you very much. One last question: parethesis after int*** are used for initialization? What if I don't use them?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211090/not-using-parentheses-in-constructor-call-with-new-c

Answer (score 0):

Note that `***ptr[4]` and `(***ptr)[4]` are *not* the same thing. The index operator (`[4]`) takes precedence over the dereference operator (`*`).

```
int ****ptr;
ptr = new int***[5];
ptr[4] = new int**;
*ptr[4] = new int*;
**ptr[4] = new int;
***ptr[4] = 77;

delete **ptr[4];
delete *ptr[4];
delete ptr[4];
delete [] ptr;
```