# Deleting pointer Instead of variable

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

From my understanding, when you allocate objects on the heap you use

```
Object* dynamicobject = new Object();
```

When I call delete I go

```
delete dynamicobject
```

I'm confused because I delete the pointer to the instance of that object, but along my line of thinking, you need to actually delete the object in memory itself which requires you to dereference the pointer like
    delete *dynamicobject
but this is incorrect. 
If you want to change the object a pointer points to, it needs to be dereferenced, and I assumed that the same applied for deletion, but it seems only the pointer can be deleted.

Comment: The `delete` operator dereferences the pointer to find the memory to reclaim.

Comment: Please note `new Object();` and `new Object;` are different

Comment: In order to delete the actual object in memory, you need to know where the object is. In other words, you need a pointer to it.

Comment: If you wanted to destroy the object itself and not give back the memory you would do `dynamicobject->~dynamicobject()`.

Comment: @EdHeal How are the two different?

Comment: @programmer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Comment: Perhaps this is easier to read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211090/not-using-parentheses-in-constructor-call-with-new-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are thinking about *destructing* the object. When you call `new`, memory is allocated for the object and its address is returned as a *pointer*. That *pointer* is a unique *identifier* recording exactly which area of memory needs to be deallocated when the object is *deleted*.

So `delete` needs to be given the pointer to the memory to deallocate.

But that doesn't kill the object. Killing the object happens by running the destructor and this is where the pointer is dereferenced.

The *destructor* function is, of course `~Object() {}`.

So `delete` will dereference the *pointer* to access the actual memory of the object by running the *destructor* function. After the *destructor* has run on the dereferenced object the memory address that the object occupied is released back to the runtime system.

So `delete` needs the *pointer* which gets dereferenced to destruct the object itself and is then used to determine exactly what *memory* to release.

Answer (score 3):

If you do

```
delete *dynamicobject;
```

the value given to the `delete` operator is the value in the dynamic memory location, not the location itself. The `delete` operator needs to know where the dynamic memory is, so it can reclaim it.

For example, suppose you do:

```
int *dynamic_int = new int;
*dynamic_int = 10;
```

If you then did:

```
delete *dynamic_int;
```

the `delete` operator would receive the integer value `10`. That doesn't provide the information it needs to reclaim the dynamic memory where that value is stored. But if you do

```
delete dynamic_int;
```

the `delete` operator receives the address of that dynamic memory, and it can reclaim it.

Answer (score 2):

The operators are parallel. `new` returns a pointer to newly-allocated memory. `delete` takes a pointer to allocated memory and deletes it. In other words, `delete (new ...())` works.

Maybe it would help to consider that `delete` fundamentally has to work with memory somehow, and not with an object, per se. Thus it needs not only the object but also the object's memory location.

Answer (score 0):

`delete dynamicobject;` does not delete the pointer `dynamicobject`. Rather, it deletes the object that `dynamicobject` points to.

You don't have to (and can't) write `delete *dynamicobject;`, presumably for similar reasons to why you don't have to write `dynamicobject = &new Object;`.

Answer (score 0):

You only deal in pointers, since dynamic memory allocation is just a big linked list of blocks. When you request a block of size **n**, the allocator searches the linked list for a block that satisfies the request. When the allocator finds the block, it returns a pointer to said block--that is, the address of the first byte in the block.

Freeing memory simply returns the block into the linked list, so that when you try to allocate memory again, that block may be reused.

All the allocator needs to know is the address of the first byte and the size. That's why it deals only in pointers.